# Why exactly does a current flow in an inductor oppose itself

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

So, I've understood that a current flow in an inductor produces

1) The original magnetic field along the direction of the curl E of the inductor.
2)Change in the magnetic field along the opposite direction of the curl E (Proportional to the original magnetic field)

I'm thinking that this change in the magnetic field will oppose the original magnetic field and reduce the magnetic field. But how will it oppose the current?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm thinking that this change in the magnetic field will oppose the original magnetic field and reduce the magnetic field.

If there is a complete electrical circuit the induced enf produces a current which opposes the **change** in the magnetic field producing it,

This means that there are cases when the induced current will try and increase the magnetic field, that is when the current passing through the inductor is decreasing.

If there was no opposition to the change then energy would be created contrary to the law of conservation of energy.

So if the current in an inductor is increasing and the induced current adds to the current then that would increase the rate at which the current increases.
The energy stored in the inductor would thus increase with no work being done to produce that increasing current.

If the induced current opposes the increasing current in the inductor then there must be an external agency doing work trying to increase the current and hence the energy stored in the inductor.

Comment: So it opposes the change in the magnetic field by opposing the current? So it attacks the current first and not the magnetic field?

Comment: @SwaroopJoshi But you must remember that the induced current produces an induced magnetic field which the tries to reduce the rate of change of magnetic flux.

Comment: Okay, so in short: Electric fields don't like to be looped?

Comment: One more doubt sir, so the basic cause for all this is the change in the magnetic field?